# Timestamp column with microsecond precision

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I am a newbie to this technology but need to get the work going for my project.

Goal:

I have a large dataset in .txt format space separated, needs to be imported to postgresql database. One of the columns is timestamp with microsecond precision.

Time column data in the .txt looks like 07:54:13.345782 which HH:MM:ss.SSSSSS format.

I am working on a postgresql installed on MAC. Using the terminal to enter commands.

I created the table

```
CREATE TABLE Shib003_data2 (
  cdate DATE NOT NULL, 
  ctime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
  location VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL, 
  status VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);
```

The ctime column refuses to copy data from my .txt file because of microsecond time precision.

I used

```
CREATE TABLE Shib003_data2 (
  cdate DATE NOT NULL, 
  ctime TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL, 
  location VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL, 
  status VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);
```

The above command doesn't go through!

Any idea how to resolve?

I can't have VARCHAR or anything else as this time is critical information for my data processing.

Comment: *The above command doesn't go through !*: are you getting an error? Please share the entire error message. `TIMESTAMP(6)` is a valid Postgres datatype.

Comment: Both create table statements work just fine, and will accept a timestamp with 07:54:13.345782: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c490126e081bccaade4cd596bb3af144  - you will need to show us how you are importing the text file. The error/problem is there, not in the table definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to `INSERT` a time into a timestamp and I'm guessing getting 'invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "07:54:13.345782"' per:

```
create table ts_precision(fld_1 timestamp, fld_2 time);
insert into ts_precision(fld_1) values('07:54:13.345782');
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "07:54:13.345782"
LINE 1: insert into ts_precision(fld_1) values('07:54:13.345782');

insert into ts_precision(fld_2) values('07:54:13.345782');
select * from ts_precision ;
 fld_1 |      fld_2      
-------+-----------------
       | 07:54:13.345782
```

So use a `time` field. The other option is to add a date portion to the time field.

Comment: Thank you very much Adrian ! The solution you provided worked and I am moving on with data import.